# How to show relational data in yii2

Tags: php, mysql, yii2

I'm having trouble understanding how relations work in yii 2

I have 2 tables in a mysql database, author and book.

book has a column named author which links to the id of the author table via foreign key.

I've generated CRUD using gii, and I want the author name to appear in the list view, as well as dropdowns for the author name in the create and update views.

But I cant seem to get the relation working even in the list view.

Here's my code

Book Model:

```
<?php

namespace app\models;

use Yii;
use app\models\Author;

/**
 * This is the model class for table "book".
 *
 * @property integer $id
 * @property string $name
 * @property integer $author
 */
class Book extends \yii\db\ActiveRecord
{
    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public static function tableName()
    {
        return 'book';
    }

    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            [['name', 'author'], 'required'],
            [['author'], 'integer'],
            [['name'], 'string', 'max' => 11]
        ];
    }

    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public function attributeLabels()
    {
        return [
            'id' => 'ID',
            'name' => 'Name',
            'author' => 'Author',
        ];
    }

    public function getAuthor()
    {
        return $this->hasOne(Author::className(), ['id' => 'author']);
    }
}
```

BookSearch Model:

```
<?php

namespace app\models;

use Yii;
use yii\base\Model;
use yii\data\ActiveDataProvider;
use app\models\Book;

/**
 * BookSearch represents the model behind the search form about `app\models\Book`.
 */
class BookSearch extends Book
{
    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            [['id', 'author'], 'integer'],
            [['name'], 'safe'],
        ];
    }

    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public function scenarios()
    {
        // bypass scenarios() implementation in the parent class
        return Model::scenarios();
    }

    /**
     * Creates data provider instance with search query applied
     *
     * @param array $params
     *
     * @return ActiveDataProvider
     */
    public function search($params)
    {
        $query = Book::find();
        $query->joinWith('author');

        $dataProvider = new ActiveDataProvider([
            'query' => $query,
        ]);

        var_dump($dataProvider);
        if (!$this->validate()) {
            // uncomment the following line if you do not want to return any records when validation fails
            // $query->where('0=1');
            return $dataProvider;
        }

        $query->andFilterWhere([
            'id' => $this->id,
            'author' => $this->author,
        ]);

        $query->andFilterWhere(['like', 'name', $this->name]);

        return $dataProvider;
    }
}
```

Also, here's the view file:

```
<?php

use yii\helpers\Html;
use yii\grid\GridView;

/* @var $this yii\web\View */
/* @var $searchModel app\models\BookSearch */
/* @var $dataProvider yii\data\ActiveDataProvider */

$this->title = 'Books';
$this->params['breadcrumbs'][] = $this->title;
?>
<div class="book-index">

    <h1><?= Html::encode($this->title) ?></h1>
    <?php // echo $this->render('_search', ['model' => $searchModel]); ?>

    <p>
        <?= Html::a('Create Book', ['create'], ['class' => 'btn btn-success']) ?>
    </p>

    <?= GridView::widget([
        'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
        'filterModel' => $searchModel,
        'columns' => [
            ['class' => 'yii\grid\SerialColumn'],

            'id',
            'name',
            [
                'attribute' => 'author',
                'value'     => 'author.name',
            ],

            ['class' => 'yii\grid\ActionColumn'],
        ],
    ]); ?>

</div>
```

Author Model:

```
<?php

namespace app\models;

use Yii;

/**
 * This is the model class for table "author".
 *
 * @property integer $id
 * @property string $name
 */
class Author extends \yii\db\ActiveRecord
{
    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public static function tableName()
    {
        return 'author';
    }

    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            [['name'], 'required'],
            [['name'], 'string', 'max' => 200]
        ];
    }

    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public function attributeLabels()
    {
        return [
            'id' => 'ID',
            'name' => 'Name',
        ];
    }


}
```

I think I may have to change something somehwhere in the author/authorSearch model.

Can someone help

thanks

Comment: You should read this : http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-output-data-widgets.html#working-with-model-relations

Comment: `[
    'attribute'=>'author',
    'value'=>$model->author->name
]`

Comment: Post your author model code too.

Comment: @MuhammadShahzad $model is not defined

Comment: Have you tried just: 'author.name' in your view widget?

Comment: `$query->joinWith('author');` replace with  ` $query->with('author');` in Book Search Model

Comment: Yes I have tried that. also tried adding $query->with('author')

Comment: pls have a [look](https://www.sitepoint.com/rendering-data-in-yii-2-with-gridview-and-listview/)

Answer (score 2):

You can also add columns to a gridview with value from an anonymous function as described here http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-grid-datacolumn.html#$value-detail. For example you can show an author's name like this in a gridview:

```
<?= GridView::widget([
'dataProvider'=>$dataProvider,
'filterModel'=>$searchModel,
'columns'=>[
    [
        'attribute'=>'author.name',
        'value'=>function ($model, $key, $index, $column) {
            return $model->author->name;
        },
    ],
    //...other columns
]);
?>
```

you can also return a html-link to the detail-view of an author like this:

```
//...
'columns'=>[
    [
        'attribute'=>'author',
        'value'=>function ($model, $key, $index, $column) {
            return Html::a($model->author->name, ['/author/view', 'id'=>$model->author->id]);
        },
    ],
    //...
],
//...
```

Answer (score 1):

You can access relation table data in any crud view file using their relation name. $model->relName->attribute_name.

And You can access relation table data in gridview at following way :

```
<?= GridView::widget([
'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
'filterModel' => $searchModel,
'columns' => [
    [
        'attribute' => 'author',
        'value'=>'author.author_name', //relation name with their attribute
    ]
],
```

]);

Answer (score 1):

First you need a get function in your model, but you have.

This is :

```
public function getAuthor()
{
    return $this->hasOne(Author::className(), ['id' => 'author']);
}
```

Now you just need do one more thing.

Go to the index file, and to GridView, and columns.

Write this into columns:

```
[
     'attribute' => 'author',
      'value' => 'author.name',
],
```

In the value, the first parameter is your Get function, what named is : getAuthor, and `.` after your column name.

Answer (score 0):

Hello in your BookSearch Mode please add below code like this.

```
$query->joinWith(array('author'));
$query->andFilterWhere(['id' => $this->id,])
->andFilterWhere(['like', 'author.author_name', $this->author]);
```

And in your view file please use below given code below code is for view file inside grid attrubute.

```
[
        'attribute' => 'author',
        'value' => 'author.name',
]
```

i hope this will helps you. and i hope in author table name is stored in name column.

Comment: `$this->id` is null, so this is not working. Thanks anyways

Comment: @ TEster please try to add id field in safe array of rules it may helps you like this  [['id','name'], 'safe']

Comment: Still no luck. I've added the above to the view file. this is now my rules method in BookSearch `    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            [['id', 'author'], 'integer'],
            [['id', 'name'], 'safe'],
        ];
    }`

Comment: @ TEster  as you are saying $this->id is null means this is from your book table id right if it in primary key have try to print value for that $this->id.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me - inside the BookSearch Model:

```
public function search($params)
{

    $dataProvider = new \yii\data\SqlDataProvider([
        'sql' => 'SELECT book.id as id ,book.author_fk, book.name as book_name , author.name as author_name' . 
                    ' FROM book ' .
                    'INNER JOIN author ON (book.author_fk = author.id) '
    ]);


    $this->load($params);

    if (!$this->validate()) {
        // uncomment the following line if you do not want to return any records when validation fails
        // $query->where('0=1');
        return $dataProvider;
    }



    return $dataProvider;
}
```

Only issue now is getting the ActionColumn to work correctly, they're currently linking to the wrong IDs, help anyone.