# Yii2 GridView Showing data from multiple tables

Tags: php, gridview, yii, yii2

I have 3 tables: `product`, `field` and `product_field`.
the product field has 2 foreign keys: `product_id` and `field_id`;

a `product` has many `product_field`s

a `field` has many `product_field`s

a `product_field` has one `product` and one `field`

the `product` table contains an id and a name(e.g. 'book'). 
the `field` table contains an id and a name(e.g. 'ean-code')
the `product_field` table contains an id, a product_id, a field_id and a value(e.g. '19886431')

relations for each table are present in the ActiveRecord Models generated by GII.

My controller action looks like this:

```
$producSearchModel = new ProductSearch();

$params = Yii::$app->request->queryParams;

$productDataProvider = $productSearchModel->search($params);

return $this->render('index', [
  'productSearchModel'   => $productSearchModel,
  'productDataProvider'  => $productDataProvider,
]);
```

My search() function in productSearchModel looks like this:

```
public function search($params){

    $query = new Query();
    $query  ->select([ '*', 'field.name as fieldname'])
      ->from('product')
      ->join(   'INNER JOIN',
          'product_field',
        'product_field.product_id = product.id'
      )  ->join(    'INNER JOIN',
        'field',
        'product_field.field_id = field.id'
      );


    $dataProvider = new ActiveDataProvider([
      'query' => $query,
      'pagination' => [
        'pageSize' => 30,
      ],
    ]);

    if (!($this->load($params) && $this->validate())) {
      return $dataProvider;
    }

    return $dataProvider;

}
```

Now everything looks fine my grid column shows 2 rows with all the fields, which is exactly what it should do.

What I want to show is a column for the **name of the field** and in each row the **value** from product_field.

What it should look like:
[image]

Can someone tell me how to achieve this?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37271207/how-to-show-relational-data-in-yii2

Answer (score 0):

You should check the below so it works:

- The product has many `product_field` so the data of the `product_field` should be visible under the product view action ex: `/product/1`
- In the `view` action of the `ProductController` you have the ID of the current product so you can do:

  ```
  $productFieldSearchModel=new ProductFieldSearch();
  $productFieldSearchModel->product_id=$productId;
  $dataProvider = $productFieldSearchModel->search(Yii::$app->request->queryParams);
  ```
- Now You can pass the to your render view having the `DetailView` of the product top and 
  below it you can have the `GridView` for the product field of this specific item

Comment: I get your point, but I want the complete result in the GridView(so no detail views)  because I want to filter and sort on the product_field.value as well. I think I need a SQL query that will return a single product row, populated by the field.names as a column, with their values from product_field.value. I don't know if this is possible